# PWA is showing the graphic glitching weird in Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, apk, progressive-web-apps

I made ASP .NET PWA and built it to .apk file.
And i tested it in Android Emulator.

But the app is rendered/shown so weird like the below image.

[image]

this is the spec of my Android Emulator.

[image]

[image]

Can i know the reason?

Comment: This may be an issue with your emulator. Not sure about anything in an APK and the emulator. You know you don't need an APK for a PWA? 
On Android (Chrome) when the user adds the PWA to the homescreen it creates an APK behind the scenes to give it more integration to the OS. No store needed, :D

Comment: I know that i don't need an APK for a PWA. But my company want a mobile app that can be installed from Google Play Store. Anyway, i couldn't resolve this glitching issue, but i tested it with the APK itself on the cell phone. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: unfortunate about the store requirement....